# mysql conditions and orders in multiple relations tables

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

I have schema like this i want to know is it possible  to have `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` in stared columns for news list.

for example where category.id = x and  cartable.status = 3 and user.id = 4 ...

```
news
-------------------------------------------------------
id*     title

category
-------------------------------------------------------
id*     title

cartable
-------------------------------------------------------
id          user_id         status*

news_category
-------------------------------------------------------
news_id     category_id

news_cartable
-------------------------------------------------------
news_id     cartable_id

user
-------------------------------------------------------
id*     name
```

sorry, updated . problem is this: each news have many category also have many cartable .. each cartable have user. so how can i sort or conditions by that fields

```
select * from news_category
left join news on (news_category.news_id = news.id)
left join category on (news_category.category_id = category.id)
--- cartable and user ???
```

Comment: ... I really don't see why not. Where's your problem? What are you actually trying to do? Have you tried using `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` on those columns? Because that would seem to be the quickest way of solving your problem... unless you actually have a different problem.

Comment: @Palladium no check the question again ... i miss some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it loooks like all the tables relate, so any of those values could potentially be used in your where clause or in an order by.  If you have an exact desired output, include it and whatever query you have tried and someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your immediate question, yes you can. As long as the tables have some relation to each other, you can use `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` to conditionalize your query.

If you need to, for instance, relate `user` to `news` (or some tables that don't immediately relate to each other), that will require you to declare every table that's in the chain of relations that links `user` to `news` (i.e.: `news_cartable` and `cartable`), as well as `WHERE` or `ON` statements to link those with each other (e.g.: `WHERE cartable_id = cartable.id AND user_id = user.id`). So if you were querying for the user(s) linked to a specific `news` entry, your code might look like this:

```
SELECT user.id FROM user, cartable, news_cartable, news
WHERE news.id = news_id AND cartable_id = cartable.id AND user_id = user.id
AND news.id = {some news ID}
```

If you wanted to `LEFT JOIN` the tables instead, you can take the conditions in the second line and write them as `ON` statements, like:

```
FROM news
LEFT JOIN news_cartable ON news.id = news_id
LEFT JOIN cartable ON cartable_id = cartable.id
LEFT JOIN user ON user_id = user.id
```

If that's also not what you're going for, state what you're specifically trying to do and I'll see what I can whip up.

EDIT: `ORDER BY` isn't conditionalizing and can be used with any column that you're `SELECT`ing. The caveat, of course, is you have to have `SELECT`ed it first in your query.